# Explain Java Unary operator

Tags: java

Do check this code:

```
int result = 0;
result = result++;
System.out.println("Result 1 = " + result);
result++;
System.out.println("Result 2 = " + result);
```

The output i was expecting was :

```
Result 1 = 1
Result 2 = 2
```

But i got the output:

```
Result 1 = 0
Result 2 = 1
```

The problem lies at Line2. Can some one explain on Unary operator.??

Comment: Good thinking, but it's actually a lot easier to read without explicit line numbering. Also, Code should be marked as such so that it can be properly highlighted and formatted.

Comment: Now "Line2" doesn't make sense. I guess either mark the line with a comment on prefix each line with "    1. ".

Comment: "The real answer to this question" is that the JLS is broken in allowing such a statement. Having said that two side effects could be aliases and method calls can have side effects on variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the statement `i = i++`:

> This is guarenteed behaviour. The value of `i` is read for the purposes of evaluating the righthand side of the assignment. `i` is then incremented. statement end results in the evaluation result being assigned to `i`.
>
> There are two assignments in `i = i++;` and the last one to be executed will determine the result. The last to be executed will always be the statement level assignment and not the incrementer/decrementer.
>
> Terrible way to write code, but there you have it a deterministic result at least.

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=318496

Answer (score 3):

When you do x++, the result is the value before the incrementation

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

> result = result++;

with:

> result++;

In the first line you're assigning zero to result. Why? Because the post-increment operator first will assign result's zero.

If you had written:

> result = ++result;

You would first increment and then assign, also getting the result you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be conscious of where you place the unary operator.   Placing `++` *after* a variable causes java to evaluate the expression using the variable then increment the variable, while placing the `++` *before* the variable causes java to increment the variable and then evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour. What is actually happening makes more sense if you look at what happens at the bytecode level when the line in question executes:

result = result++;

> registerA = result  (registerA == 0)
>   result += 1  (result == 1) -- These first two lines are the result++ part
>   result = registerA (result == 0)

The variable "result" is being assigned twice in this statement, once with an increment, and then again with the value prior to the increment which basically makes it a noop.